# приложение на javafx не отвечает

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу прогу на java и графический интерфейс для нее на javafx все было хорошо. Но в один момент начала выскакивать ошибка java tm platform se binary не отвечает.
Всплывает это тогда когда я хочу передать что то серверу.
Каковы причини возникновения этой ошибки

Comment: Бесконечные циклы... Код бы увидеть

Comment: Для решения проблемы прикрепите код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что я хотел впихнуть информацию в буфер который меньше ее...
Извините. Перепутал условия. Должно было быть "пока буфер вмещает", а получилось "пока есть что пихать".